# Access Sum by matching date. Sorting doesn't work

Tags: sorting, date, ms-access, sum, match

Ok, so I've got a schedule for teachers with following headings
[Date=>StartTime=>EndTime=>Type=>Teacher=>Discipline=>Hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnSlF.gif)

It's taking the account of Hours spent with students
For a report in the end of the month

The point is to sum all mathching

```
    Date=>         =>         =>Type=>Teacher=>Discipline=>
```

### And I did so by Using Sum

```
    SELECT DISTINCTROW Format$([Sched].[Date],'Long Date') AS Date, [Sched].[Tacher], [Sched].[Discipline], [Sched].[Type], Sum([Sched].[Hours]) AS [Sum Of Hours]
    FROM [Sched]
    GROUP BY Format$([Sched].[Date],'Long Date'), [Sched].[Tacher], [Sched].[Discipline], [Sched].[Type];
```

---

The problem is if you try to sort this by date it looks like smth is wrong with Date

[april 1=>april 13=>15=>16=>april 2(???)=>20=>23=>27=>6(???)=>8=>9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lQnR.gif)

How can I test this for an error?

Comment: Does resizing Access fix anything?

Comment: because you might have here a string comparison

Comment: Just to clarify, this question is only about the incorrect sorting?

Answer (score 0):

You can't order date strings with this format.

Order by date value:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    Format$([Sched].[Date],'Long Date') AS Date, [Sched].[Tacher], [Sched].[Discipline], [Sched].[Type], Sum([Sched].[Hours]) AS [Sum Of Hours]
FROM 
    [Sched]
GROUP BY 
    Format$([Sched].[Date],'Long Date'), [Sched].[Tacher], [Sched].[Discipline], [Sched].[Type]
ORDER BY 
    [Sched].[Date], [Sched].[Tacher], [Sched].[Discipline], [Sched].[Type];
```

or use a sortable date format:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    Format$([Sched].[Date],'yyyy-mm-dd') AS Date, [Sched].[Tacher], [Sched].[Discipline], [Sched].[Type], Sum([Sched].[Hours]) AS [Sum Of Hours]
FROM 
    [Sched]
GROUP BY 
    Format$([Sched].[Date],'yyyy-mm-dd'), [Sched].[Tacher], [Sched].[Discipline], [Sched].[Type];
```